# How to add expressions to labels in facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset from which I would like to plot small multiples, specifically in a 2-by-2 array, like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(letter = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 20)), x = rnorm(80), y = rnorm(80))
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm") + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ letter, ncol = 2)
```

However, I want each facet label to include an expression, such as

```
expression(paste("A or ", alpha))
```

I can make this happen using `facet_grid()` via

```
f_names <- list('A' = expression(paste("A or ", alpha)), 'B' = expression(paste("B or ", beta)), 'C' = expression(paste("C or ", gamma)), 'D' = expression(paste("D or ", delta)))
f_labeller <- function(variable, value){return(f_names[value])}
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm") + geom_point() + facet_grid(~ letter, labeller = f_labeller)
```

But then I lose the 2-by-2 array.  How can I rename the `facet_wrap()` facet labels with an expression?  Or, how can I solve this by recreating the 2-by-2 array using `facet_grid()`, but only faceting by a single variable?

(This question builds off of the parenthetical note in @baptiste's answer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151123/how-to-specify-columns-in-facet-grid-or-how-to-change-labels-in-facet-wrap).)

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151123/how-to-specify-columns-in-facet-grid-or-how-to-change-labels-in-facet-wrap

Comment: @baptiste:  Yes!  Thank you, the `facet_wrap_labeller()` function in the Q&A to which you linked works great. @Ricardo: Thanks for that link -- I had found that answer, and it pushed me toward the question originally.  Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to do what I asked, first load this labeller function from @Roland first appearing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979017/changing-facet-label-to-math-formula-in-ggplot2):

```
facet_wrap_labeller <- function(gg.plot,labels=NULL) {
  #works with R 3.0.1 and ggplot2 0.9.3.1
  require(gridExtra)

  g <- ggplotGrob(gg.plot)
  gg <- g$grobs      
  strips <- grep("strip_t", names(gg))

  for(ii in seq_along(labels))  {
    modgrob <- getGrob(gg[[strips[ii]]], "strip.text", 
                       grep=TRUE, global=TRUE)
    gg[[strips[ii]]]$children[[modgrob$name]] <- editGrob(modgrob,label=labels[ii])
  }

  g$grobs <- gg
  class(g) = c("arrange", "ggplot",class(g)) 
  g
}
```

Then save the original `ggplot()` object:

```
myplot <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm") + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ letter, ncol = 2)
```

Then call `facet_wrap_labeller()` and feed the expression labels as an argument:

```
facet_wrap_labeller(myplot, labels = c(expression(paste("A or ", alpha)), expression(beta), expression(gamma), expression(delta)))
```

The expressions should now appear as the `facet_wrap()` labels.

Comment: Simpler way to use it, not needed to pass an expression on every field of the labels, neither the "labels": facet_wrap_labeller(myplot, expression(paste("A or ", alpha), beta, gamma, delta))

Comment: For anyone attempting this more currently, a solution within ggplot has now been implemented. There is a nice example at the bottom of the [ggplot index](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/labellers.html) that shows how to do this very handily with facet_wrap.