# How to change the facet labels in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, facet-wrap

I am using ggplot and facet_wrap to get the required plots. I have to add few things to the labels of each facet or the variable or the name of each facet, just like how we modify the xlab and ylab directly under ggplot.

**Example:**

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) +
  xlim(0, 2) + stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

d + facet_wrap(~ color)
```

[image]

All I want to do now is to change the label of each facet i,e D,E,F,G,H,I,J to something else.

How can I modify this?

**Addition**

Sorry I tried to break it but, it take time so I have added it in github.
You can upload the file and check the result.
The problem is with the option 4 facet_wrap...you can select the radio button option 4.

I have commented the previous facet_wrap I was using where the data integrity is fine, but if I change the facet wrap, the graph behaves differently and also the data.

Data to upload can be found in the folder "Data to upload"

Code can be found here: I will add this in a minute

Comment: related popular question but for `facet_grid` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472980/ggplot-how-to-change-facet-labels

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on what I know, `facet_grid` might be a better solution in this case. `facet_grid` can not only help you group plots by one variable, but also two or even more, there is an argument called `labeller` which is designed to customize the label.

```
myfunction <- function(var, string) {
  print(var)
  print(string)
  result <- paste(as.character(string),'_new', sep="")
  return(result)
}

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) + xlim(0, 2) + 
  stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + facet_grid(~color, labeller=myfunction, as.table=TRUE)

# OUTPUT
[1] "color"
[1] D E F G H I J
Levels: D < E < F < G < H < I < J
```

[image]

However, as you can see, the plot is in one row and I don't think it can be easily broken into multiple rows even if you turned on the `as.table` flag based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151123/how-to-specify-columns-in-facet-grid-or-how-to-change-labels-in-facet-wrap).

Do you think it will be feasible if you add a new column dedicated for labelling? Then you can keep the awesomeness of `facet_wrap`...

```
diamonds$label <- paste(as.character(diamonds$color), "_new", sep="")
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price, fill = ..density..)) + xlim(0, 2) + 
  stat_binhex(na.rm = TRUE) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1) + facet_wrap(~label)
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine. But I dont know why its behaving strangely in my dataset. If I follow your proposal then values are repeating, I mean same value is there in all the facets. I have added my code to the question please check.

Comment: I had problem passing reactive component value to the new label name. I fixed it now. Thanks for your great answer.

Answer (score 9):

Though its a very old question , i would like to answer it for i learnt one easy method!!

This solution is with facet_wrap() and without changing your data in any manner also.

```
text.on.each.panel <-"_new"
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
     xlim(0, 2) 
d + facet_wrap(~ color, labeller = label_bquote(.(color)-.(text.on.each.panel)))
```