# How can I build a long selectInput list and then use it to change the labels in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

This question is with reference to [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030179/how-to-change-the-facet-labels-in-facet-wrap)

The above question is regarding changing the labels of a facet_wrap, the answer is perfect --> add a modified label as a new column of the dataset.

Now, the problem I am facing is --

User selects multiple variables `selectInput("select", h4("Variables:"), choices=var.both1(), selected=var.both1()[1], multiple=T, width="100%")`

(for ex: lets consider `input$select` length can be 6)
now `input$select` contains six variables, I want to check each variable and assign units to it, and I can partially achieve this with the following reactive component

```
variableunit <- reactive ({
  if(input$select == "TEPC") {"degC"}
  else if(input$select == "AT"){"µmol/kg"}
  else if(input$select == "DIC" | input$select == "DIN" | input$select == "PIC" | input$select == "POC" | input$select == "PON" | input$select == "POP" | input$select == "DOC" | input$select == "DON" | input$select == "DOP" | input$select == "TEP"){c("µmol/L")}
  else if(input$select == "Chla"){"µg/L"}
  else ("Meters")  
})
```

the `variableunit` here gets a single value, even the user enters 6 variable, `variableunit` can give me only one single value.

how can I have a list of 6 values inside `variableunit` so that I can use it in the below ggplot facet_wrap

**The Code**

```
    server <- function(input, output) {

  a <- reactive({
    fileinput1 <- input$file1
    if (is.null(fileinput1))
      return(NULL)
    read.table(fileinput1$datapath, header = TRUE, col.names = c("Ei","Mi","hours","Nphy","Cphy","CHLphy","Nhet","Chet","Ndet","Cdet","DON","DOC","DIN","DIC","AT","dCCHO","TEPC","Ncocco","Ccocco","CHLcocco","PICcocco","par","Temp","Sal","co2atm","u10","dicfl","co2ppm","co2mol","pH"))
    #read.table(fileinput1$datapath, header = TRUE, col.names =  c("Experiment","Mesocosm","Hour","Nphy","Cphy","CHLphy","Nhet","Chet","Ndet","Cdet","DON","DOC","DIN","DIC","AT","dCCHO","TEPC","Ncocco","Ccocco","CHLcocco","PICcocco","PAR","Temperature","Salinity","CO2atm","u10","DICflux","CO2ppm","CO2mol","pH"))  
    #a$Chla <- a$CHLphy + a$CHLcocco  #Add new columns as per observation data
    #a$PON <- a$Nphy + a$Nhet + a$Ndet + a$Ncocco 
  })

  output$showMapPlot <- renderUI({
{ list(plotOutput("plot",height="100%"), br()) }
  })



  output$select <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(a())){selectInput("select", h4("Variables:"), choices=names(a()), selected=NULL, multiple=T, width="100%")}
  })


variableunit <- reactive ({
  if(input$select == "TEPC") {"degC"}
  else if(input$select == "AT"){"µmol/kg"}
  else if(input$select == "DIC" | input$select == "DIN" | input$select == "PIC" | input$select == "POC" | input$select == "PON" | input$select == "POP" | input$select == "DOC" | input$select == "DON" | input$select == "DOP" | input$select == "TEP"){c("µmol/L")}
  else if(input$select == "Chla"){"µg/L"}
  else ("Meters")  
})


  plot_4 <- function(var1 = input$select[1], var2 = input$select[2], var3 = input$select[3], var4 = input$select[4], var5 = input$select[5], var6 = input$select[6]) {
    myvars <- c(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6)
    withProgress(message = 'Processing please wait...', value = 0, {
    gg4 <- aggregate(cbind(get(var1),get(var2),get(var3),get(var4),get(var5),get(var6))~Mi+hours,a(), FUN=mean)
    names(gg4)[3] <- var1
    names(gg4)[4] <- var2
    names(gg4)[5] <- var3
    names(gg4)[6] <- var4
    names(gg4)[7] <- var5
    names(gg4)[8] <- var6
    dd <- melt(gg4,id.vars=c("Mi","hours"), measure.vars=myvars)
    dd$label <- paste(as.character(dd$variable), "(", (variableunit()), ")", sep="")
    print(ggplot(dd,aes(x=hours, y=value)) + 
            geom_point(aes(color=factor(Mi)), size = 3, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))  +
            geom_smooth(stat= "smooth" , alpha = I(0.01), method="loess", color = "blue") +
            facet_wrap(~label, nrow=3, ncol=2,scales = "free_y") + scale_color_discrete("Mesocosm") )
})
  }

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if(length(input$select) == 6){
    plot_4() 
    }
},
height=700, width=1100
)
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(3,
      uiOutput("showMapPlot"),
      wellPanel(
        h4("Data Upload"),
        fileInput('file1', h5('Choose Your Model Data'), accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.OUT'))),
      wellPanel(h4("Variable selection"),uiOutput("select"))

    ),
    column(9,
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel("Conditional Plots",plotOutput("plot",height="auto"),value="barplots"),
             id="tsp"))
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**File to upload**
[Download here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B54s5NXDypdMRmdsSjZnMzd5VVE/edit)

Just copy paste the code and execute it.

**Now the problem**
is first variables unit is repeating for all other plots. I know this is the problem with the reactive component that I am using to get the units of the variables.

**The Question** 
Now is, how to do that ?

I am stuck here from a long time, really hoping somebody knows the workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use `reactiveValues()`? For example: `values <- reactiveValues()`. Inside your reactive function: `variableUnit <- reactive({ if(input$select == "TEPC") {values$var1 <- "degC"}}`

Comment: @MikaelJumppanen thats fine. But ggplot starts plotting once it gets all six variables....so if input$select is having 6 values finally then how can I handle the above methond in this case. (ultimately how can I have a list of 6 values inside variableunit, according to the user selected 6 values ?)

Comment: In `selectInput()` there is only one variable selected at time and input$select will return that one selected value.

Comment: but reactivevalues() should have list of all 6 variables entered by user. I have added posted my complete github regarding this. Please check. You can check "option 2"(which uses single variable and it changes the label of facet fine.) and "option 3" (which uses 6 variables and here facet labels are repeating with the first variable and also the plot values, I know the reason but cant able to handle it properly)

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you follow these guidelines: [How to create minimal, complete, and veriable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I would want to see minimal shiny code about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried with the above answer and I will end up getting this error **"Error : nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE"**. Please let me know if somebody knows the work around.

```
server <- function(input, output) {


  #File Upload
  a <- reactive({
    fileinput1 <- input$file1
    if (is.null(fileinput1))
      return(NULL)
    read.table(fileinput1$datapath, header = TRUE, col.names = c("Ei","Mi","hours","Nphy","Cphy","CHLphy","Nhet","Chet","Ndet","Cdet","DON","DOC","DIN","DIC","AT","dCCHO","TEPC","Ncocco","Ccocco","CHLcocco","PICcocco","par","Temp","Sal","co2atm","u10","dicfl","co2ppm","co2mol","pH"))
  })


  #Plot
  output$showMapPlot <- renderUI({
{ list(plotOutput("plot",height="100%"), br()) }
  })


  #Variable Input
  output$select <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(a())){selectInput("select", h4("Variables:"), choices=names(a())[-c(1,2,3)], selected=NULL, multiple=T, width="100%")}
  })




  #Function to plot the variables
  plot_4 <- function(var1 = input$select[1], var2 = input$select[2], var3 = input$select[3], var4 = input$select[4], var5 = input$select[5], var6 = input$select[6]) {
    myvars <- c(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6)
    withProgress(message = 'Processing please wait...', value = 0, {
    gg4 <- aggregate(cbind(get(var1),get(var2),get(var3),get(var4),get(var5),get(var6))~Mi+hours,a(), FUN=mean)
    names(gg4)[3] <- var1
    names(gg4)[4] <- var2
    names(gg4)[5] <- var3
    names(gg4)[6] <- var4
    names(gg4)[7] <- var5
    names(gg4)[8] <- var6
    dd <- melt(gg4,id.vars=c("Mi","hours"), measure.vars=myvars)


    #Reactive element to get the unit corresponding to the variable entered
    variableunit <- reactive({
      test <- c("TEPC", "Chla", "DIN", "PIC", "AI", "PON")    
      values <- list()
      for(i in 1:length(test)) {

        if(test[[i]] == "TEPC") {
          values[[i]] <-"degC"
          next
        }else if(test[[i]] == "AT"){
          values[[i]] <-"µmol/kg"
          next
        }else if(test[[i]] == "DIC" | test[[i]] == "DIN" | test[[i]] == "PIC" | test[[i]] == "POC" | test[[i]] == "PON" | test[[i]] == "POP" | test[[i]] == "DOC" | test[[i]] == "DON" | test[[i]] == "DOP" | test[[i]] == "TEP"){
          values[[i]] <-"µmol/L"
        }else if(test[[i]] == "Chla"){
          values[[i]] <-"µg/L"
        }else{
          values[[i]] <-"Meters"
        }
      }

      return(values)
      #return(paste(as.character(test), "(",values,")", sep=""))
      #dd$label <- paste(as.character(test), "(",values,")", sep="")
    })

    print(paste(variableunit()))
    dd$label <- paste(as.character(dd$variable), "(", variableunit(), ")", sep="")
    #dd$label <- variableunit()

    print(names(dd))
    #print(unique(dd$variable))
    #print(unique(dd$value))
    print(ggplot(dd,aes(x=hours, y=value)) + 
            geom_point(aes(color=factor(Mi)), size = 3, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))  +
            geom_smooth(stat= "smooth" , alpha = I(0.01), method="loess", color = "blue") +
            facet_wrap(~label, nrow=3, ncol=2,scales = "free_y") + scale_color_discrete("Mesocosm") )
})
  }

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if(length(input$select) == 6){
    plot_4() 
    }
},
height=700, width=1100
)
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(3,
      uiOutput("showMapPlot"),
      wellPanel(
        h4("Data Upload"),
        fileInput('file1', h5('Choose Your Model Data'), accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.OUT'))),
      wellPanel(h4("Variable selection"),uiOutput("select"))

    ),
    column(9,
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel("Conditional Plots",plotOutput("plot",height="auto"),value="barplots"),
             id="tsp"))
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I could not achieve what I wanted with the melted data, but in my case I am doing aggregate of data then melting. So I just changed the data to whatever way I wanted after the aggregate itself and before melting, so all the variable names are now updated and ready to put into facet panels.
**Below is the code:**

```
server <- function(input, output) {


  #File Upload
  a <- reactive({
    fileinput1 <- input$file1
    if (is.null(fileinput1))
      return(NULL)
    read.table(fileinput1$datapath, header = TRUE, col.names = c("Ei","Mi","hours","Nphy","Cphy","CHLphy","Nhet","Chet","Ndet","Cdet","DON","DOC","DIN","DIC","AT","dCCHO","TEPC","Ncocco","Ccocco","CHLcocco","PICcocco","par","Temp","Sal","co2atm","u10","dicfl","co2ppm","co2mol","pH"))
  })


  #Plot
  output$showMapPlot <- renderUI({
{ list(plotOutput("plot",height="100%"), br()) }
  })


#Variable Input
output$select <- renderUI({
  if(!is.null(a())){selectInput("select", h4("Variables:"), choices=names(a())[-c(1,2,3)], selected=NULL, multiple=T, width="100%")}
})

#Reactive Element to update the units
variableunit <- reactive({
  #test <- c("TEPC", "Chla", "DIN", "PIC", "AI", "PON")    
  test <- input$select
  values <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(test)) {

    if(test[[i]] == "TEPC") {
      values[[i]] <-"degC"
      next
    }else if(test[[i]] == "AT"){
      values[[i]] <-"µmol/kg"
      next
    }else if(test[[i]] == "DIC" | test[[i]] == "DIN" | test[[i]] == "PIC" | test[[i]] == "POC" | test[[i]] == "PON" | test[[i]] == "POP" | test[[i]] == "DOC" | test[[i]] == "DON" | test[[i]] == "DOP" | test[[i]] == "TEP"){
      values[[i]] <-"µmol/L"
    }else if(test[[i]] == "Chla"){
      values[[i]] <-"µg/L"
    }else{
      values[[i]] <-"Meters"
    }
  }

  return(values)
})



#Function to plot the variables
plot_4 <- function(var1 = input$select[1], var2 = input$select[2], var3 = input$select[3], var4 = input$select[4], var5 = input$select[5], var6 = input$select[6]) {
  myvars <- c(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6)
  withProgress(message = 'Processing please wait...', value = 0, {
    gg4 <- aggregate(cbind(get(var1),get(var2),get(var3),get(var4),get(var5),get(var6))~Mi+hours,a(), FUN=mean)
    names(gg4)[3] <- paste(var1,"(",variableunit()[1],")")
    names(gg4)[4] <- paste(var2,"(",variableunit()[2],")")
    names(gg4)[5] <- paste(var3,"(",variableunit()[3],")")
    names(gg4)[6] <- paste(var4,"(",variableunit()[4],")")
    names(gg4)[7] <- paste(var5,"(",variableunit()[5],")")
    names(gg4)[8] <- paste(var6,"(",variableunit()[6],")")
    dd <- melt(gg4,id.vars=c("Mi","hours"), measure.vars=c(names(gg4)[3],names(gg4)[4],names(gg4)[5],names(gg4)[6],names(gg4)[7],names(gg4)[8]))

    print(ggplot(dd,aes(x=hours, y=value)) + 
            geom_point(aes(color=factor(Mi)), size = 3, position = position_jitter(width = 0.1))  +
            geom_smooth(stat= "smooth" , alpha = I(0.01), method="loess", color = "blue") +
            facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=3, ncol=2,scales = "free_y") + scale_color_discrete("Mesocosm") )
  })
}

output$plot <- renderPlot({
  if(length(input$select) == 6){
    plot_4() 
  }
},
height=700, width=1100
)
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(3,
                  uiOutput("showMapPlot"),
                  wellPanel(
                    h4("Data Upload"),
                    fileInput('file1', h5('Choose Your Model Data'), accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.OUT'))),
                  wellPanel(h4("Variable selection"),uiOutput("select"))

  ),
  column(9,
         tabsetPanel(
           tabPanel("Conditional Plots",plotOutput("plot",height="auto"),value="barplots"),
           id="tsp"))
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If someone knows a way to achieve this after the melting of the data then please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Q:"how can I have a list of 6 values inside variableunit so that I can use it in the below ggplot facet_wrap"

A: You can have list of 6 values inside reactive function. Use for loop to go through `input$select`. And save corresponding unit to same index in a list.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

      variableunit <- reactive({
      test <- c("TEPC", "Chla", "DIN", "PIC", "AI", "PON")    
      values <- list()
      for(i in 1:length(test)) {

        if(test[[i]] == "TEPC") {
        values[[i]] <-"degC"
        }else if(test[[i]] == "AT"){
        values[[i]] <-"µmol/kg"
        }else if(test[[i]] == "DIC" | test[[i]] == "DIN" | test[[i]] == "PIC" | test[[i]] == "POC" | test[[i]] == "PON" | test[[i]] == "POP" | test[[i]] == "DOC" | test[[i]] == "DON" | test[[i]] == "DOP" | test[[i]] == "TEP"){
        values[[i]] <-"µmol/L"
        }else if(test[[i]] == "Chla"){
        values[[i]] <-"µg/L"
        }else{
        values[[i]] <-"Meters"
        }   
    }

  return(paste(as.character(test), "(",values,")", sep=""))
})

      output$text <- renderText({
        variableunit()
        print(paste(variableunit()))
      })
    }

    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

        ),
        mainPanel(textOutput("text"))
      )
    ))

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This example renders text: TEPC(degC) Chla(µg/L) DIN(µmol/L) PIC(µmol/L) AI(Meters) PON(µmol/L)

Comment: Thanks...after generating the units I have to update them to the corresponding variables...that I am trying to do with                         paste(as.character(dd$variable), "(", (variableunit()), ")", sep="")                                                                          but I will end up with error Error : nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE

Comment: Sorry @statisticalbeginner, you didn't highlight me by using @ so I didn't notice your comment. If I modifie my answer to `return(paste(as.character(test), "(",values,")", sep=""))` it prints: 
TEPC(degC) Chla(µg/L) DIN(µmol/L) PIC(µmol/L) AI(Meters) PON(µmol/L) is that what you want?

Comment: Error comes because your function `variableunit` doesn't return list only one variable. In my answer I modified the function so that it will return list.

Comment: ...Thanks...In your example it works...but I am trying to update the units into a column named label in the dataset "dd"...and I am getting error because I can read individual variables but not corresponding individual units...I have to find a way to get individual units corresponding to the variables and update a new column named label in dataset "dd"...so that if I use this updated dataset in facet_wrap I will get the result I needed.