# How to edit facet wrapped bar plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph here:
[image: Graphs of variables from sites 2-6]

```
dframe1$row <- row.names(dframe1)
library(reshape2)
dframe2 <- melt(dframe1, id=c("Site", "row"))
ggplot(dframe2, aes(x=as.numeric(row), fill=Site, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +       facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")
```

Basically I would like to know how I can change the colours so that they are different for each site (represented in the legend), and if it is possible to label the x and y axes individually for each mini graph and to get rid of the as numeric line at the bottom.

Here is the dput() of my data:

```
structure(list(Site = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), weight = c(0.193, 0.249, 0.263, 
0.262, 0.419, 0.204, 0.311, 0.481, 0.326, 0.657, 0.347, 0.239, 
0.416, 0.31, 0.314, 0.277, 0.302, 0.403), cell.count = c(2530000, 
729000, 336000, 436000, 292000, 0, 2e+05, 6450000, 2e+05, 18700000, 
7430000, 9920000, 22700000, 21600000, 227000, 169000, 5e+05, 
283000), eleocyte = c(1270000, 17, 7.3, 264000, 0, 0, 2e+05, 
0, 2e+05, 2270000, 0, 9920000, 22700000, 442, 153000, 169000, 
5e+05, 283000), lambda.max = c(459L, 459L, 459L, 459L, 462L, 
462L, 462L, 462L, 462L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 465L, 490L, 490L, 475L, 
475L, 475L), avepb.ppm = c(390.2, 373.3, 340.13, 403.2, 248.53, 
206.7, 238.5, 190.6, 597.2, 206.8, 174.4, 186.3, 138.5, 269.55, 
58.1, 5.225, 4.02, 6.85), aveworm.pb.ppm = c(9.59, 9.446, 4.193, 
21.9, 1.66, 7.415, 13.11, 3.01, 51.5, 5.985, 4.705, 26.38, 2.38, 
4.44, 4.67, 0.11, 0.085, 0.096), aveworm.g = c(0.09125, 0.264, 
14.699, 0.2425, 0.4793, 0.051, 0.0635, 0.0465, 0.2645, 0.0559, 
0.0795, 0.05765, 0.0846, 0.457, 0.0625, 0.0535, 0.1576, 0.16)), .Names = c("Site", 
"weight", "cell.count", "eleocyte", "lambda.max", "avepb.ppm", 
"aveworm.pb.ppm", "aveworm.g"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Comment: which column ist __row__ i get this error: `Error: id variables not found in data: row`

Comment: As Floo0 mentions your code doesn't quite run, but to get a different `fill` per site you need to define it as a `factor` ie`fill=factor(Site)`. Currently it is treated as continuous (an integer).

Comment: Apologies. This code needs to go first dframe1$row <- row.names(dframe1) before library(reshape 2). I have included it in the edit. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the colors you need to tell ggplot that Site is a factor (as @user20650 pointed out in the comments).

You already have individual axes for the mini graphs because you specified `scales = "free"` in `facet_wrap()`.

To get rid of the as.numeric(row) label at the bottom of your graph you can specify that you do not want text there with the `theme()` statement. You could also achieve this by adding a blank label with `p <- p + xlab("")` instead of the `theme()` line.

This code produces the following figure:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(dframe2, aes(x = as.numeric(row), fill = as.factor(Site), y = value))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
p <- p + scale_fill_discrete("Site")
p <- p + theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())
p
```

[image]

To change the labels of the facets you can change the levels of the variables in your data frame. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473306/3267983). Similar to:

```
levels(dframe2$variable) <- c("Weight", "Cell Count", "Eleocyte", "Lambda",
                              "Average PPM", "Average PB PPM", "Average G")
```

If you use `facet_grid` instead of `facet_wrap` you can  use a labeller function (in case you do not want to change your data frame). See also the [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151123/how-to-specify-columns-in-facet-grid-or-how-to-change-labels-in-facet-wrap).

The [Cookbook for R site](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/) is also a good resource for faceting questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I mean (with regards to the mini axes), how I could add individual labels to them? I.e. so that I could specify units etc. Also I would like to change the header titles in R, I have tried using colnames() but it does not work..

Comment: @KB2 I updated the answer to include how to change the labels of the facets. I am not sure about the first question and do not have an easy answer. Good luck!